# tf.feature_column is only usable when eager mode is enabled?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm running https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/keras/feature_columns#create_a_feature_layer

It works fine when eager is enabled, but errors with `ValueError: column_name: thal input_tensor dtype must be string or integer. dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>.` if eager is turned off.

I was trying to use [shared embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/shared_embedding_columns) , and it requires non-eager mode.

So basic feature_column code above runs only when eager mode is enabled, 
and shared_embedding requires eager mode turned off.

How can I have both?

Comment: Running into this as well, were you able to get it worked out?